# How to modify style for an asp:textbox in codebehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, styles

I am trying to set the style of an asp:TextBox in codebehind, the textbox is style is set initially to
 `style="display:none"` 
when I set the dispaly to block in codebehind the textbox appears for a moment and then it's gone. I don't know what this problem is, when it's done in javascript it works fine

Here is the code:

asp.net code:

`<asp:TextBox ID="txtError" style="display:none"  runat="server" ReadOnly="True" Width="95%"></asp:TextBox>`

codebehind:

```
txtError.Style["display"] = "block";
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any .NET control has `Visible` property - you should use it in case you don't need control to be shown later (if Visible is set to false control won't be rendered at all).

Regarding your issue - I think there is some client (javascript) code that changes style of textbox back to `display:none`;

Comment: I found that there is a Window.Load event in the javascript code that resets the property. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

If you use

```
txtError.Visible = false;
```

You can not access the text box using JavaScript.
If you want to just change visibility you can use

```
txtError.Style.Add("display", "none");
```

Answer (score 0):

What about setting the Visible property?

```
txtError.Visible = false;
```

If this also doesn't work then somewhere else you will be re setting the value to none. Also check whether any of the parent elements of the textbox is not hidden.

Also no need to set the display of a textbox to block(if not intended so), use inline instead.